# How to make python module logger work with any main logger?

Tags: python, logging

I've developed a module that I would like to be imported into any script and automatically have the module logger hiearchy below the logger established in the main script, no matter what the main logger is called (root, main, etc.)

i.e.

a.py

```
import module
log = logging.getLogger()
log.info("Test Main")
test()
```

b.py

```
import module
log = logging.getLogger('main')
log.info("Test Main")
test()
```

module.py

```
mod_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def test():
    mod_log.info("Test Mod")
```

If the script ran successfully, I would expect the following output. I just can't seem to get it to run?

a.py

```
ROOT - Test Main
ROOT.module - Test Mod
```

b.py

```
main - Test Main
main.module - Test Mod
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because there is no way to tell where a logger was defined and which one the "main" logger is supposed to be. The main script could define any number of loggers, including zero. The only logger that is guaranteed to exist is the `root` logger.

If you are fine with just taking a guess you could make your logger a child of whatever is the first logger that was created.

module.py

```
import logging

logger_name = __name__

if logging.root.manager.loggerDict:
    parent = next(iter(logging.root.manager.loggerDict))
    logger_name = parent + '.' + logger_name

mod_log = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I assumed this to be possible, because I feel like i've downloaded modules before that did this, but I may have been missing something key. 
Maybe I should change my question to, Is there anyway I can make the logging in the module safely execute, no matter what script imports it?

Answer (score 0):

Implement a Singleton Design pattern of the Logger class - whose basically job is to add a formatter, setting logging level and filtering and finally returning an instance of the logger.

Then use this to create an object:

```
logger = Logger.__call__().get_logger()
print(Logger())
```

Following the above method will create one and only on instance of logger and no matter where you create the object of the Logger class, it will be the same old instance if it was created before.